# Flutter: Conflict between TextField's onTap and prefixIcon's onPressed

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

When the prefixicon is clicked, onTap will be called back automatically. How to ban it?

```dart
          child: TextField(
            onTap: ReplyController.to.onClickTextField,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              prefixIcon: IconButton(
                onPressed: ReplyController.to.openEmojiField,
                color: Colors.black,
                icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.smiley),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `FocusNode` to the TextField to have access whether the field is actually focused. And now if you want to ignore the onTap when textfield has focus you could modify the `onTap` such as `onTap: !focusNode.hasFocus? ReplyController.to.onClickTextField : null`