# How to disable Flutter DatePicker?

Tags: flutter, datepicker, flutter-textformfield, flutter-textinputfield, flutter-date-range-picker

I have an issue with `DatePicker` in my application. Here's a simple `TextFormField` that I've created in my app which will open up `DatePicker` whenever the user taps on it.

[image]

This widget is a part of a form where I also have specified the `GlobalKey` and `TextController` for it. The rightmost calendar icon uses the `suffixIcon` property of `InputDecoration` and it changes to a clear icon whenever the user selects a date.

Here's the code for the above widget.

```
       TextFormField(
          onTap: () => _selectStartDate(context),
          controller: _startDateTextController,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.datetime,
          readOnly: true,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            suffixIcon: showClear ? IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
              onPressed: _clearStartDate,
            ) : Icon(Icons.date_range),
            labelText: 'Start Date',
            labelStyle: TextStyle(
              fontSize: AppDimensions.font26,
              color: AppColors.paraColor
            ),
          ),
          validator: (value){
            if(value!.isEmpty) {
              return 'Please enter a date';
            }
          },
        ),
```

My goal is to let the user pick on a date, and clear it should they choose to do so.

Here's the code for the `_selectStartDate` and `_clearStartDate` functions as well as the necessary controller and key. I'm using the `intl` package to format the date.

```
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  TextEditingController _startDateTextController = TextEditingController();
  DateTime selectedStartDate = DateTime.now();
  bool showClear = false;

  _selectStartDate(BuildContext context) async {
    final DateTime? newStartDate = await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: selectedStartDate,
      firstDate: DateTime(1900),
      lastDate: DateTime(2100),
      helpText: 'STARTING DATE'
    );
    if(newStartDate != null && newStartDate != selectedStartDate) {
      setState(() {
        selectedStartDate = newStartDate;
        _startDateTextController.text = DateFormat.yMMMd().format(selectedStartDate);
        showClear = true;
      });
    }
  }

  _clearStartDate() {
    _startDateTextController.clear();
    setState(() {
      showClear = !showClear;
    });
  }
```

When i run the app, the `DatePicker` pops up and I'm able to select a date. The date is then shown on the `TextFormField` like the image below.

[image]

As you can see the clear icon is displayed. However, when i clicked on it, the `DatePicker` still popped up. And when i clicked on cancel on the `DatePicker` window, the `TextFormField` is cleared as expected.

[image]

Here's the complete code.

```
class BookingForm extends StatefulWidget {
  const BookingForm({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _BookingFormState createState() => _BookingFormState();
}

class _BookingFormState extends State<BookingForm> {

  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  TextEditingController _startDateTextController = TextEditingController();
  DateTime selectedStartDate = DateTime.now();
  bool showClear = false;

  _selectStartDate(BuildContext context) async {
    final DateTime? newStartDate = await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: selectedStartDate,
      firstDate: DateTime(1900),
      lastDate: DateTime(2100),
      helpText: 'STARTING DATE'
    );
    if(newStartDate != null && newStartDate != selectedStartDate) {
      setState(() {
        selectedStartDate = newStartDate;
        _startDateTextController.text = DateFormat.yMMMd().format(selectedStartDate);
        showClear = true;
      });
    }
  }

  _clearStartDate() {
    _startDateTextController.clear();
    setState(() {
      showClear = !showClear;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: AppDimensions.width20, right: AppDimensions.width20),
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(AppDimensions.height20),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white70,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(AppDimensions.radius20),
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Color(0xFFe8e8e8),
              blurRadius: 5.0,
              spreadRadius: 1.0,
              offset: Offset(2,2)
            ),
          ]
        ),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            TextFormField(
              onTap: () => _selectStartDate(context),
              controller: _startDateTextController,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.datetime,
              readOnly: true,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                suffixIcon: showClear ? IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
                  onPressed: _clearStartDate,
                ) : Icon(Icons.date_range),
                labelText: 'Start Date',
                labelStyle: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: AppDimensions.font26,
                  color: AppColors.paraColor
                ),
              ),
              validator: (value){
                if(value!.isEmpty) {
                  return 'Please enter a date';
                }
              },
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: AppDimensions.height10,
                  bottom: AppDimensions.height10,
                  left: AppDimensions.width45,
                  right: AppDimensions.width45
                ),
                primary: AppColors.mainColor2,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(AppDimensions.radius20)
                )
              ),
              child: SmallText(
                text: 'Search',
                size: AppDimensions.font26,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              onPressed: (){
                if(_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                  _formKey.currentState!.save();
                }
              }
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I'm not sure why this happens. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter: Conflict between TextField's onTap and prefixIcon's onPressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68845904/flutter-conflict-between-textfields-ontap-and-prefixicons-onpressed)

Comment: Can remove all padding and try tapping on button point. failed to get the issue, Also what do you mean by disabling the date picker, for me tapping suffixIcon doesnt pop up the dialog

Comment: @eamirho3ein I tried the solution on that question, but the datepicker is totally disabled. But I'm not sure if i implemented the focus node correctly.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh what i want to achieve is to disable the onTap of the TextFormField temporarily whenever the suffixIcon (which is wrapped in IconButton) is clicked, is it possible to do that?

Comment: Yes, I think, you like to disable the tap event after getting date?  also tapping on suffix Icon is not opening the dialog on my test case